# Low power, low performance stepper motor

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I am looking for some small (and cheap) stepper motors that can be driven with <3V and a maximum current draw of 100mA. I'm trying to drive one using a lithium coin battery. Torque can be very low, e.g., 0.01kg/cm.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: I am curiouse wjat is your application.

Comment: Related question here... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30316/smallest-stepper-motor-that-one-could-buy

Comment: @bigjosh back when shopping questions were treated more charitably.

Comment: There is a plentiful supply of tiny autofocus stepper motors on eBay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are happy enough with unidirectional motion, you could hack the mechanism from an analog quartz clock. They will operate from 1.5V pulses and draw perhaps 10mA in short pulses.

100mA is definitely on the high side for any kind of coin battery.

---

If you are willing to go to two batteries in series, there are small bipolar (4-wire) steppers used in GM (General Motors, not Genetically Modified) automotive instrument panels. The coils draw about 20mA @5V  and incorporate a gear train. 1mm shaft diameter. They fail so often that plenty of replacements are available on the aftermarket.

Comment: You might be right: OP just wants to drive a needle.

Comment: I'd look at watch stepper motors also. These are very very low power and low voltage, and can often be driven bidirectionally. More info in this datasheet for a watch motor driver... http://www.nxp.com/products/signal-chain/analog-watch-motor-drivers/32-khz-watch-circuits-with-adaptive-motor-pulse:PCA1462U